# Highcharts yLow / yHigh not working

Tags: highcharts

I have an inverted columnrange graph where my labels sometimes overlap. A solution would be to apply a y-offset to my label with the yLow and yHigh attributes, causing the low label to be at the bottom of the bar and the high label to be at the top. However, these attributes don't seem to have any effect. The xLow and xHigh attributes work just fine. Am I doing something wrong?

Please see my example here: http://jsfiddle.net/M2jhL/2/ The code in question is my dataLabels formatting:

```
...
plotOptions: {
    columnrange: {
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            formatter: function () { return "label: "+this.y; },
            color: "#ffffff",
            xLow: 65,
            xHigh: -65,
            yLow: -20,
            yHigh: 20
        },
        color: "#123456"
    }
},
...
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's a bug, reported [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2409). Thanks!

Comment: an upvote for finding a legitimate bug in your code would be appreciated. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Pawel for the bug report. Using the notes from the report, I was able to edit my local copy of the Highcharts-more.js source code to provide a workaround. Basically, I just need to comment out the `if (inverted)` check (and the analogous change on the `[xy]Low` part of the code):

```
//if (inverted) {
    dataLabelOptions.align = 'left';
    dataLabelOptions.x = dataLabelOptions.xHigh;                                
//} else {
    dataLabelOptions.y = dataLabelOptions.yHigh;
//}
```

As my app only uses a range graph in a single place, I am confident that this change does not break anything else for me.